# upload build into Itunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile, testflight

I'm using iOS developer account which is not enrolled(not paid) in program. However, I was invited in Itunes Connect to be developer of company account, so my role in Itunes Connect is developer.

Now I need to upload application build into TestFlight on Itunes Connect, but I can't archive it because of missing provisioning profile in xCode for this application. As my account not enrolled I don't have option to generate distribution and development provisioning profiles in developer page. So I requested company manager to provide me: distribution and development profiles. Receiving them I found that they are with .cer extension and XCode don't recognize them. May be thats because there are only valid for Apple ID owner of the creator.

I read all Apple documentation on this topic, but this issue is not covered or I didn't found it.

**How can I get provisioning profiles in this situation?** 
And then upload build into Itunes Connect for app that I'm only developer. Do I need to enroll my developer account? Or company have to invite my in other place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .cer only contains the certificate used to sign the binary as the company.  It should open in the Keychain Access app, not Xcode. You need to ask the representative to also send you the .p12 file, which would contain the private key for the certificate.  Without that private key, you can't build an app as the organization you are working with.

Once you have those, you should be able to log into the Apple developer site and download the provisioning profiles for iOS Development and iOS Distribution.  Those should open in Xcode.  Once you have all 3 things (the private key, cert, and provisioning profile), you should be able to build the app.

Answer (score -1):

There are **four** roles you can grant to the users for them to access all the data about specific apps:

**1. App Manager:** The App Managers can edit all aspects of the apps they
    have access to, and can add users to those apps. These users can be
    granted limited app access.

**2. Developer:** The Developer user has access to My Apps and Resources
    and Help. They can upload binaries to iTunes Connect and manage
    internal TestFlight users. These users can be granted limited app
    access.

**3. Marketer:** The Marketer role is for users who manage marketing
    materials and promotional artwork. Users with the Marketing role
    will be contacted by the App Store team if an app is chosen to be
    featured on the App Store. They can update app metadata and request
    promo codes from My Apps. These users can be granted limited app
    access.

**4. Sales:** The Sales role has access to Sales and Trends, and iTunes
    Connect for iOS. They can only download the full sales reports if
    they also have the Reports role. Sales users can be granted limited
    app access.

All of these roles support limited app access, which is the ability to restrict accounts to only view certain apps. Granting Admin or Finance automatically provides the ability to see every app associated with the developer program membership.

Comment: I know that, and I have Developer role in Itunes Connect. But I can't create provisioning profile, so that my application build could be uploaded to TestFlight even though I'm Developer in Itunes Connect.